# winapi Не работает WM_NCPAINT когда окно потеряло фокус

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как можно отрисовывать то что рисуется в WM_NCPAINT когда окно потеряло фокус?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: решил проблему 
`case WM_NCACTIVATE:
SendMessage(hWnd,WM_NCPAINT,0,0);
break;`

Comment: добавлю что из WM_NCACTIVATE надо выходить return 1; а не break;